# Problema para redondear bordes de una tabla html con css

Tags: html, css

no consigo redondear los bordes de una tabla html simplemente quiero redondear los dos bordes superiores pero se me hace imposible.

Esto es lo que estoy usando:

```css
.ejemplo {
  border: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<table class="ejemplo">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Prueba
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Prueba
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el HTML de la tabla a la que tratas de dar estilo? Viendo tan el CSS es imposible determinar que te puede estar fallando

Comment: si ahora mismo, listo

Comment: ¿Alguna hoja de estilo que estés utilizando? He probado un snippet y funciona correctamente.

Comment: Tu código funciona bien, como se puede ver en el ejecutable. Por favor, crea un [mcve] para que podamos ver el problema en la propia pregunta.

Comment: En qué navegador pruebas?

Comment: El código que has puesto hace lo que pides.

Comment: Hoy en día no es necesario utilizar prefijos para `border-radius`. El problema tiene que ser el otro CSS que tienes y que no podemos ver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creo que tu problema es con las clases por defecto que trae el elemento.
podrías intentar agregando !important al final de cada estilo.
algo asi:

```
.ejemplo{
  border: 1px solid #a7a7a7 !important;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: lo he probado y nada, el border por ejemplo funciona es solo el redondear lo que no y por cierto no funciona con el borde pero si conotras cosa..

Comment: El ejemplo original funciona correctamente, parece ser que se tienen algunos elementos adicionales que faltan mencionar a @jorge.

Comment: Se considera una mala práctica usar en exceso la regla `!important`. El usuario A. Cedano nos da una explicación muy detallada de su uso, pueden verla aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/203733/83304

Comment: puede ser que uso Blade ? o no debe influir?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar de esta manera:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

th, td {
  padding: 1em;
  background: #ddd;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white; 
}

body {
  margin: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Nombre
      </td>
      <td>
        Edad
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Mario
      </td>
      <td>
        55
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Juan
      </td>
      <td>
        20
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```