# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el color del Dropdown cuando le doy click?

Tags: css, bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No estoy seguro de si hay alguna solución de que cuando le doy click tenga otro color, gracias.

```
``<div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-invi dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-display="static" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Perfil
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-lg-left">
                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Mi Perfil</button>
                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Configuración</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Cerrar Sección</button>
                    </div>
```

``

Comment: Está un poco difícil decirte exactamente cómo, porque no sabemos cómo lo estás implementando, deberías de compartir tú código. Por favor sigue las recomendaciones del [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y la [guía de cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Gracias, lo tendré presente en una próxima.

<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-lg-left">
      <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Mi Perfil</button>
      <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Configuración</button>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Cerrar Sección</button>
</div>

Comment: No agregues tu código en los comentarios, agrégalo a tu pregunta editándola y usando el formato para código. No uses imágenes para compartir código, eso va en contra de las reglas. Por favor échale un vistazo  a la [guía de cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Gracias FranAcuna. Creo que de esa manera la menos quedo algo mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Para ello debes jugar con el CSS y sobrescribir los default de bootstrap.

```
ul.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #00AEFE;
}
ul.dropdown-menu:hover {
    background-color: #00AEFE;
}
.nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:focus, .nav .open > a:hover {
    background-color: #00AEFE;
}
.nav > li > a:focus, .nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #00AEFE;
}
```

Comment: La línea correcta en la v4 es `.dropdown-item.active, .dropdown-item:active`, el OP menciona el cambio de color al hacer click, más que al hacer hover

Answer (score -1):

Con el css y para que me coja el color que quiero y no por defecto los de bootstrap uso !important prueba con esto

```
#dropdownMenuButton {
    background-color: red !important;
    border: none !important;
}
.dropdown-item:hover{
background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Usar `!important` es una mala práctica, ¿seguro que es estrictamente necesaria?

Comment: Pésima práctica, por favor revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/203733/83304